# Elegant way for pattern matches with List-entrys Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

whats the common way of solving a situation where you have a text

> this is an awesome text and nothing else matters

and i have a List like

```
[ "nothing","bread","butter","fool" ]
```

and i want to check if any of the words in the String is inside the list

my soulution so far is :

```
 Boolean check = false
 String myString = "this is an awesome text and nothing else matters"
 List myList = [ "nothing","bread","butter","fool" ]

 def stringlist = myString.tokenize(" ")
 stringlist.each{ 
    if( it in myList ){
      check = true
    }
 }
```

Is there a more performant or better elegant way to handle this ?

How do i handle punctuation marks ?

For any suggestions thanks in advance

Comment: What would be an example of punctuation mark in the string?

Comment: "for example: this string, is comma seperated and a colon is inside" and tokenizing would split out "string," and "example:" or ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at using some of the collection methods. [Intersect](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) comes to mind.

```
def myString = "this is my string example"
def words = ['my', 'list', 'of', 'stuff']

def matches = myString.tokenize(" ").intersect(words)
println matches
def check = (matches.size() > 0)
```

Comment: that looks good, thanks for implementing the boolean :D if i wanted to handle the punctuation marks i just have to make a regex-replace with the tokenized bits or ?

Comment: I would use a regex to normalize the string before hand.

Comment: You're very welcome. It's fun to discover new Groovier ways to do things.

Answer (score 3):

Extending what Joshua has pointed out (using intersect) and adding a regex (considering the simplest case of string [alphanumeric]), something like below can be done:

```
String myString = "for example: this string, is comma seperated 
                   and a colon is inside - @Self"
List myList = [ "nothing","bread","butter","fool", "example", "string", "Self" ]

assert myString.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/).toList().intersect(myList) 
                 == ["example", "string", "Self"]
```

Also note, intersect returns the conjunction of those two collections which you can apply as Groovy truth as well (`[]` is false of both lists are disjoint)

Comment: Maybe adding [Porter Stemming](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt)? ;-)

Comment: Wow. Good candidate for common-extensions? ;) @tim_yates

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to handle punctuation marks is

```
String myString = "for example: this string, is comma separated and a colon is inside - @Self"
List myList = ["nothing", "bread", "butter", "fool", "example", "string", "Self"]

Boolean check = false
myList.each {
    if (myString.contains(it)) {
        check = true 
    }
}
```

Comment: gr8. or simply `myList.findAll { myString.contains(it) }`